# Rest request url

Tags: php, rest

I have this this url

```
POST https://DomainName/api/v1/loans/{loanId}/transactions?command=repayment
```

which is used to post data to a php software that exposes its functionality via REST.

In the docs,this information is given

```
POST loans/5/transactions?command=repayment
Content-Type: application/json
Request Body:
{
  "dateFormat": "dd MMMM yyyy",
  "locale": "en",
  "transactionDate": "14 May 2013",
  "transactionAmount": "500.00",
  "paymentTypeId": "12",
  "note": "check payment",
  "accountNumber": "acc123",
  "checkNumber": "che123",
  "routingCode": "rou123",
  "receiptNumber": "rec123",
  "bankNumber": "ban123"
}
```

This is just an example `loans/5/transactions?command=repayment` where `loanid` was entered which is `5`

How can i include other parameters given in the request body into a url?.

Comment: Are you just asking how to make a POST request?  What are you using to make the request?  It's not really clear what the problem is.

Comment: @David Here is the api https://demo.openmf.org/api-docs/apiLive.htm#loans_transaction_repayment

Comment: Ok, and where are you stuck?  What are you using to access that API?  How have you tried to send a POST request, and in what way did the attempt not succeed?

Comment: My question is the format the request body parameters should be in. Should the parameters be entered this way `loans/5/transactions?command=repayment?locale="en"`?... or what normally happens in rest?

Comment: The documentation shows the example format.  The request body would be a JSON object in the format you provided in the question.

Comment: Is it possible to have a json object in the url without having to a programming language or curl?

Comment: If you URL-encode the entire object, yes.  Though I don't see how that would help you here since the API expects it to be in the request body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you request a server with HTTPs POST function, the payload data is not sent in the URL. If you send the payload data in the URL it is called a GET request.

To send payload data using the POST function (data is in a json format as in your case) you can use the curl tool.

For example:

curl --data "
{
  "dateFormat": "dd MMMM yyyy",
  "locale": "en",
  "transactionDate": "14 May 2013",
  "transactionAmount": "500.00",
  "paymentTypeId": "12",
  "note": "check payment",
  "accountNumber": "acc123",
  "checkNumber": "che123",
  "routingCode": "rou123",
  "receiptNumber": "rec123",
  "bankNumber": "ban123"
}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://DomainName/api/v1/loans/{loanId}/transactions?command=repayment

This is run from the command line. Where are you doing the request? Is it in a program or is it something you would like to do only once?

Comment: This is the api i am trying to communicate with https://demo.openmf.org/api-docs/apiLive.htm#loans_transaction_repayment

Comment: Ok, can you clarify your question. Are you just asking for how to do a POST request?

Comment: How would i do the post request with the provided request parameters without having to use curl?

Comment: It depends on where you are doing your request. There are multiple libraries for different languages that perform a POST request for you.

Comment: @LeQs: You'd use some other tool or method for building and sending a POST request.  What are you currently using?  It sounds like you're asking, "How do I interface with a REST API?"  In which case, `curl` is one of the many ways you'd do that.

Comment: I do not want curl,i was thinking of php but the plain url would have been better lie when using a blueprint api http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api  In blueprint,i could interact easily with the database via rest

Comment: @LeQs: In PHP you'd probably also use `curl`.  (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)  Though you could certainly use any other tool which does the same thing.  If you're asking for tool recommendations, those are off-topic for Stack Overflow.